# Why does my TCS not await?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, taskcompletionsource

The `async` keyword *do* cause the [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) to change (even if there's no await inside the method), but it is primarily to allow `await` to be present.

But I did not expect the following to happen:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = Go();
    t.Wait();
}

static async Task Go()
{
    Console.WriteLine(1);
    await AAA(3000);
    Console.WriteLine(2);
}


static  Task<object> AAA(int a) // <--- No `async`
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    Task.Delay(a).ContinueWith(b => tcs.SetResult(null));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This print:

```
1
(wait)
2
```

But if I change

```
static  Task<object> AAA(int a)
```

to

```
static async  Task<object> AAA(int a)
```

It prints:

```
1
2
(no wait)
```

**Question**

Why don't I see the delay? The TCS is only resolved after three seconds. Meanwhile, the task is not resolved and should be awaited.

Comment: I think [razor118](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32785865/477420) answer is the best demonstration of the problem  - change `static  Task<object> AAA(int a)` to `static  Task<int> AAA(int a)` (with necessary changes to code) and than add `async`.

Comment: Yeah I got bitten by the <object> as T. thinking of it now - it's a stupid question. Every async method's result that returns something  - that something is wrapped by a Task. So here I'm actually returning `Task<Task>`

Comment: Stupid or not it your call, but definitely educational (and well written). Both versions of code (async/non-async) look plausible and puzzled me (and I bet enough people based on votes).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without the `async` keyword you are returning the `TaskCompletionSource`'s task from `AAA` and so you wait for it to complete (which will happen after the delay completes).

However, when you add the `async` keyword , the task returned from the method is the **state-machine's task that completes synchronously**. That task has inside it (as a result) the `TaskCompletionSource`'s task but that isn't the task you are waiting on.

If you want that method to wait for the `TaskCompletionSource`'s task you can await the inner task of `Task<Task>`:

```
await ((Task) await AAA(3000));
```

Or await the `TaskCompletionSource`'s instead of returning it:

```
async Task AAA(int a)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    Task.Delay(a).ContinueWith(b => tcs.SetResult(null));
    await tcs.Task;
}
```

Or even better, just awaiting the `Task.Delay` itself:

```
async Task<object> AAA(int a)
{
    await Task.Delay(a);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because when you return `Task` from an async method with a return type of `Task<object>` what you get it `Task<Task>` with your task (that you expect to be awaited) inside. That what you should do:

```
static async Task<object> AAA(int a)
{
  await Task.Delay(a);
  return null;
}
```

In short, try to avoid mixing async-await and direct task operations in one method.

Answer (score 2):

As Serg mentioned, look at this example in Visual Studio:

```
        static async Task<int> AAA(int a) // <--- No `async`
        {
             TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
             Task.Delay(a).ContinueWith(b =>
             {
                  tcs.SetResult(1);
             });
             return tcs.Task;
        }
```

You will get error like this:

**Since this is an asynchronous method, the return expression must be of type 'int' rather than 'Task'**, because your method will run synchronously. That's why it is required to return `int`, not `Task`.

Comment: With respect to your last sentance, the method *will* run wynchronously, and it does require an `int` and not a `Task<int>` be returned, but the fact that the method runs synchronously isn't *why* he has to return an `int`.  He needs to return an `int` because all `async` methods wrap the returned value in a `Task`.  That this method will run synchronously is true, but not the reason for that error.

Comment: razor118, That answer would be brilliant as comment - using some strong type instead of `Object` would have made error very obvious. Or you can clean it up by applying @Servy's comment.

Comment: Serv as I know async keyword is responsible to inform compiler to build state machine. It doesn't wraps return type to Task<returnType>. Look at the IL code of that
private static void Test() {  }

and

private static async void TestAsync(){}

Comment: @razor118 `async` doesn't wrap return *type* (that's why it still is `Task<int>`) but it wraps the *return* (that's why you have to return `int`)